# How to use "none" as a pronoun

Tags: grammar

I don't know how to use "none" as a pronoun. For example :

> "I drank all the coffee. There are none left."

Why "none" here is a pronoun? What noun did it replace?

Comment: I drank all the coffee. There is none (= no coffee) left.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that there must be a noun for a pronoun to replace. This is not so. What noun does "you" replace? A pronoun functions grammatically as a noun phrase, but there is not necessarily a single noun that it semantically replaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Dictionary.com, **none** as a pronoun has the following meanings: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/none

> **none**[nuhn]
>
> pronoun
>
> 1. no one; not one: 
>      *None of the members is going.*
> 2. not any, as of something indicated: 
>      *None of the pie is left. That is none of your business.*
> 3. no part; nothing: 
>      *I'll have none of your backtalk!*
> 4. (used with a plural verb) no or not any persons or things: 
>      *I left three pies on the table and now there are none. None were left when I came.*

I thought this might be helpful... Here, 4. says "(used with a plural verb)", but your example uses coffee, which is uncountable unless it's expressed as a cup of coffee, two cups of coffee... ..., so the verb that needs to be used for your example is "is" and it will be:

> "I drank all the coffee. There is none left".

And what is replaced by none in this sentence is ***no coffee*** as in AlanCarmack's comment. Hope you find this helpful:)